# app was closed JobService not running periodically

Tags: android, service, jobservice

I have a Jobservice that runs periodically every time.My activity only is to job start for running on the app.i can stop or destroy the app manually using UI and the JobService not running ,the jobservice why stop i don't know.i attached the my manifistfile and Jobdispatcher what i do something else?

```
     dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(getActivity()));
                Bundle myExtrasBundle = new Bundle();
                myExtrasBundle.putString("some_key", "some_value");
                if (myJob == null) {
                    myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                            // the JobService that will be called
                            .setService(ReminderService.class)
                            // uniquely identifies the job
                            .setTag("my-unique-tag")
                            // one-off job
                            .setRecurring(true)
                            // don't persist past a device reboot
                            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                            // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
                            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
                            // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
                            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                            // retry with exponential backoff
                            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
                            // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
                            .setConstraints(
                                    // only run on an unmetered network
                                    Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK
                            )
                            .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
                            .build();

                    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
                }


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.vvsugar">

        <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <permission
            android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

        <application
            android:name=".AppController"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:installLocation="internalOnly"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="DATABASE"
                android:value="vvsugae.db" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="VERSION"
                android:value="1.45" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="QUERY_LOG"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
                android:value="com.vvsugar.dbview" />

            <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
            </provider>

            <activity
                android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service
                android:name="com.vvsugar.activity.ReminderService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false"
                android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>



            <activity android:name=".activity.DashBoardActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".base.BaseActivity" />
            <activity
                android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" />
            <activity android:name=".uicomponent.imagepicker.activities.AlbumSelectActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".uicomponent.imagepicker.activities.HelperActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".uicomponent.imagepicker.activities.ImageSelectActivity" />
            <activity
                android:name=".adapters.PaymentsAdapter"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_payments_adapter"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyBwdtoapVVM-Yg4VIKNuFaH8f3GqN7pd98" />
            <!--
                 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
                android:value="eab11ffa174990145b21fef7ed3fd2ddcf6ca4c8" />

            <activity android:name=".activity.ActiveWindow"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: your service is automatically closing after some time when app is closed.? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yes, when i app closed not running

Comment: On modern Android, all background services are stopped after a few minutes.  Either make it a foreground service, or write your code such that it doesn't need a persistent service.

Comment: @GabeSechan JobScheduler is intended to work at certain intervals, so will it cause that much battery draining issues?Thereby can it
 work even when there's no instance of app?

Comment: JobScheduler is used to minimize battery issues, by batching jobs to be done and not keeping background processes running.  Android will instantiate your app to run your job id needed.

Comment: it is ok but what i do for running jobservice for continually.

Answer (score 0):

On your Job service return true on onStartJob

```
 override fun onStartJob(jobParameters: JobParameters): Boolean {
     return true
    }
```

also override onStartCommand like this

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return Service.START_STICKY
    }
```

and for menifest write code like this

```
<service
    android:name=".JobServiceEx"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

Your service will look like this for **Kolin** code

```
class JobServiceEx : JobService() {

   var startTime: Long = 0
   val workHandler = Handler()
   var workRunnable: Runnable? = null

// Called by the Android system when it's time to run the job
override fun onStartJob(jobParameters: JobParameters): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job started!")

    workRunnable  = object : Runnable {

        override fun run() {
            val millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
            var seconds = (millis / 1000).toInt()
            val minutes = seconds / 60
            seconds %= 60
            var curTime = "$seconds"
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Current Sec : $curTime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.e("TAG", "Current Time : $curTime")
            workHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }
    workHandler.post(workRunnable)

    return true
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    return Service.START_STICKY
}




// Called if the job was cancelled before being finished
override fun onStopJob(jobParameters: JobParameters): Boolean {

    workHandler.removeCallbacks(workRunnable);

    return false
}

companion object {
    private val TAG = JobServiceEx::class.java.simpleName
 }
}
```

and start and stop service like this

```
   R.id.buttonStart -> {

            /**
             * start job service to test
             */
            var componentName = ComponentName(this, JobServiceEx::class.java)
            var jobInfo: JobInfo? = null

            jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .setMinimumLatency(1)
                .setOverrideDeadline(1)
                .build()

            var jobScheduler = getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
            var resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
            if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Job scheduled!");
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", "Job not scheduled");
            }


        }
        R.id.buttonStop -> {

            /**
             * stop job service to test
             */
            val jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
            jobScheduler.cancel(JOB_ID)

        }
```

Comment: That flag doesn't really work like that on modern Android versions.  Your service will be stopped and not restarted due to background processing limits.

Comment: I faced lot of problems in service for Orio or later and now this is working for me very well for Orio and the previous version.

Comment: @HemendraGangwar All background services are killed after a few minutes on Oreo and later.  Either your service is doing its work in that time, your app is in the foreground, or it isn't working like you think it is.  See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: Yes I am agree and  that's why the JobService and JobIntentService was introduce for foreground service using JobScheduler . You can check this on the same tutorial on Note.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Please check this [blog](https://hackernoon.com/android-location-tracking-with-a-service-80940218f561)